# javascript show/hide not working in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, hide, show

could you please help me, how to fix this code to make it working in firefox and IE?

If you drop card2 -> card3 will not show in firefox

```
  $(".stackDrop").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card1, .card2",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        if($(event.toElement).hasClass("card1")){ $('.card2').hide(); };
        if($(event.toElement).hasClass("card2")){ $('.card3').show(); };
    }
  });
```

There is a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/70x2set8/3/

Comment: Add more details or sample code, where is problem ?

Comment: Hello, I have just uploaded jsfiddle with my problem...It does not work in firefox and ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the impression that a whole example here is done in bad way. I'm not sure what is your target but there is general problem with events in browsers.

Sometimes chrome, FF, IE etc show events in wrong way or have different properties names.

In your example property `.toElement` in FF is undefined thats why its not working.

You can fix it probably by changing it to `event.originalEvent.target`.
https://jsfiddle.net/x25wjs6j/

```
    if($(event.originalEvent.target).hasClass("card1")){ $('.card2').hide(); };
    if($(event.originalEvent.target).hasClass("card2")){ $('.card3').show(); };
```

In addition check your Jquery version. First set of jQuery versions support IE and other old things and another one not but use some new features. Check it - it can start work after changing jQuery version.

Anyway next time describe better what do you need and where is piece of not working code.

Comment: I do not know how to express gratitude, but I am so glad!! I am impressed by your knowledge! thanks a million!!